# Non Blocking Sockets vs Blocking sockets - UDP - C&linux

Tags: design, c, networking, sockets, protocol

When to use blocking sockets over non blocking sockets on UDP?

Question 1:What's is recommended for the following scenario ?

Multiple clients send data over multiple UDP sockets, i.e. say client1 sends data over sockets 100, 101, 102,..,105 . client2 on sockets 110,111,112...115 etc. Port numbers are fixed for clients. Number of clients are fixed(10).
So totally 10 * 5 sockets.

Data on each sockets(atleast 3 sockets) is sent every few milliseconds.
The other 2 sockets are for sending commands and getting data.

After receiving the data there is some IO involved where i write to disks.
(I cant change any of the above. i.e. number of sockets ,etc )

Question 2:Is it best to use Threads for this scenario (or) Asynchronous IO multiplexing with nonblocking sockets?

Comment: Are that many sockets really neccessary? Anyway, I'd use `select()` to read from any socket, then dispatch to a thread.

Comment: I can't change that as its already decided that way. You mean select() with non blocking sockets ?

Comment: select() with blocking. For non-blocking you could use recvfrom() for each socket in a separate thread.

Comment: In blocking whats that you are planning to use to receive data other than recvfrom(). Can you please point to an example or pseudocode. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The usual way is to use [`poll()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select), which ever you find more to your liking, with blocking sockets. Since they accept any file descriptors, same loop can be used for inter-thread or inter-process communication with a socket pair, or reading input from stdin.

A good, quite short and to the point, reading is [*Beej's Guide to Network Programming
Using Internet Sockets*](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html). Check out [section about `select()`](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/advanced.html#select) for a small example program [source](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c). That uses TCP and not UDP, so you'll need to do some adapting, but UDP will probably just make things simpler (unless your use case is re-implementing TCP functionality on top of UDP, which almost never is a good idea).

You may want to do processing in separate threads (or even processes, depending on requirements), or just inside that same loop, depending on how heavy this is: "*After receiving the data there is some IO involved where i write to disks.*" I'd start with a single-threaded implementation and see how it goes, before making it more complex.

Comment: Thanks. How do i create threads per socket on using Select().

Comment: @m4n07 point of select is, you don't need thread per socket, you can use for example a thread pool. So when your select loop in main thread gets an UDP packet, you put it to a queue and notify worker threads to pick it up. If you have a static number of sockets, you can create thread per socket, each working independently (with blocking read, or a select loop in each thread).

Comment: Thanks hyde. For the first method can you pls point to a example.As  i tried im able to get the data from multiple sockets using select() , How do i do notify the worker threads in C.

Comment: @m4n07 Well, for ring buffer implementation, [this question has example answers about ring buffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703707). Other than that, google... But I'd create first version without threads, just isolating the UDP packet handling to a function which takes just one struct as argument (so you can easily move it to another thread once single-threaded code works).